# Prepopulate Okta Registration Widget

Tags: okta

I'm trying to use standard (official) **Okta Sign In Widget** - I need a way to fill out some fields automatically on that **Registration Widget**. For example User Name and Last Name.

I know that I can do it through API, but wondering if there is a way to use query string parameters or something like that.

Wondering if there is a way to do that?